# How to transform a list of parameter in an array

Tags: c++

I want to transform a list of parameter of the same type into a C array.
This is the best way I have found to solve the problem:

```
template <typename T > class _Arr {
    template <size_t N> struct Rep_base {
        T m_el[N]; 
        operator T * () { return m_el; } 
    }; 
public:
    template <size_t N> struct Rep; 
    template <> struct Rep<1> : public Rep_base<1> {
        Rep(const T & a) { m_el[0] = a; };
    }; 
    template <> struct Rep<2> : public Rep_base<2> {
        Rep(const T & a, const T & b) { m_el[0] = a; m_el[1] = b;}; 
    };
    ... 
};
```

So given a function:

```
void f(int x[5]);
```

if is possible to call `f(_Arr<int>::Rep<5>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)).`

It is horrible. Has anyone a better solution?

Comment: Well, in C++11 you can do `f(std::vector<int>({1,2,3,4,5}).data())`, which is somewhat nicer.

Comment: Can't you just do `int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; f(x)`?

Comment: Or it would be better to use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it as a secondary function and aren't using C++11, you can use variable arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> var_func( int n, ... ) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n);
    std::vector<int> args;
    for(int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        args.push_back(va_arg(ap, int));
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return args;
}

void f(int x[5]) {
    for( int i = 0; i != 5; ++i ) std::cout << x[i];
}

int main() {
    f( var_func(5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).data() );
    return 0;
}
```

Output is `12345`

Comment: In the question the function given is fixed. Technically this approach would also work with a function that takes a pointer to ints and iterates over it, or functions that accept different sized static arrays. But I'm not 100% on what the OP is using this function for so I could stand corrected. Hm.. The person I responded to just deleted their comment..

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reinventing the wheel? C++ already has pre-built containers that do exactly want you're attempting. If you want a dynamically-sized array, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). If you want a fixed-sized array, use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). These are the alternatives you should be considering.

Comment: No initializer list on my compiler. I like the solution that uses a std::array. I will keep mine until it will be available.

Comment: @MarcoAmagliani You don't need to use the initializer list for this. You can use `.push_back` as well (for `std::vector`). Also, can you consider accepting an answer to this question. It helps a lot.